# Should these two be the same? NotificationChannel.setGroup and Notification.Builder.setGroup

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

While creating notification channels, I categorise them by assigning them to a group (NotificationChannel.setGroup).
Later, while displaying notification, I use Notification.Builder. Should the value given to setGroup method here be the same as the first to function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Even though they might be related in your business rules, channel groups and notification groups are used for different reasons.

As stated in https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels:

> If you'd like to further organize the appearance of your channels in the settings UI, you can create channel groups. This is a good idea when your app supports multiple user accounts (such as for work profiles), so you can create a notification channel group for each account. This way, users can easily identify and control multiple notification channels that have identical names.

So, if you set different **channel groups** they'll be displayed separately in App Info -> Notifications. I'd say you just need it if your app has multiple channels and you want to further organize them.

A **notification group**, the one you set in `Notification.Builder.setGroup()`, is used to group notifications in the notification tray. You can learn more about it at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group.